# guildMemberAdd discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

```
const ids = [
 "(discord user ids)",
 "",
 ""
]

client.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {
  for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
   if (member.id.includes(ids[i])) {
  console.log["test"];
}
}});
```

This code above is meant to not let the people with these discord ID's in. I didn't finish coding it so I just want it to log when people with those ID's join, but when i put in a discord id and had the person join it did not log anything just acted as if it didn't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`member.id` does not return an array so you can't use use `includes()` on it.

You need to compare `member.id` to all the IDs in your `ids` array.

So you can do this in two ways.

**Recommended**: Use `includes()` properly:

```js
client.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {
   if (ids.includes(member.id)) {
       member.ban() // or `member.kick()`
   }
})
```

Or you could check if `ids[i]` is equal to `member.id`

```js
client.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {
for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
   if (ids[i] == member.id) {
      member.ban() // or `member.kick()`
   }
}
})
```

Side note: `console.log[]` is not a thing, you need to use `console.log()`